# Creating the right SOAP call in PHP

Tags: php, soap

I'm having trouble creating the right SOAP call in PHP. I've tested the following call in SOAP UI and it works, but I've tried everything from creating objects, arrays and SOAPHeaders and I can't seem to get the right call. Here is the request that works in SOAP UI:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:com="com.dtn.aghost.API.subscriptions">
    <soapenv:Header>
        <com:ServiceCredentials>
            <usernamePasswordCombo>
                <username>[username]</username>
                <password>[password]</password>
            </usernamePasswordCombo>
        </com:ServiceCredentials>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body>
        <com:SubscriptionServiceIdList>
            <visible>1</visible>
        </com:SubscriptionServiceIdList>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had some questions as your request has very little information regarding what you've already tried. I suggest you add some of the code that you have attempted to use and some of the resources you've looked at to get that information. In addition it would help to answer your request if you described the results of what you tried. Such as were there errors if so what errors did you see?

A good place to look to get examples of PHP code connecting to a SOAP web service would be the PHP documentation about the [Soap Client](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapclient.php).

In the comments of that page you will find examples of code that others have used. You may be adapt that to use that for your purposes.

As for an example of code connecting to a SOAP web service

```
<?php

    $http_client = 'http://example.com/MyService.asmx?wsdl';

    $client = new SoapClient($http_client, array(
        'style' => SOAP_DOCUMENT,
        'use' => SOAP_LITERAL,
        'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
        'trace' => 1,
        'connection_timeout' => 300));

    $params = array( 'username' => $user_name, 'password' => $password);

    $results = $client->myFunction($params);

    // Debug code can be added after this

?>
```

Another thing that you will need to do is debug the results of the request. In the example above it sets the value of trace to 1. This allows you to debug the SOAP request that has taken place. You can do that with the following code.

```
    // Debug code

    echo $client->__getLastRequestHeaders();
    echo $client->__getLastRequest()
    echo $client->__getLastResponseHeaders();
    echo $client->__getLastResponse();
```

[PHP SoapClient getLastResponse](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastresponse.php)

Last of all you can use [is_soap_fault](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-soap-fault.php) to determine if the request failed. There are some good code examples on the PHP documentation for getting the error code of what happened.